# How come a daily build is behind snapshot releases like beta or RC?

Tags: 10.10, firefox

I installed Firefox 4 from the daily builds PPA, and it doesn't seem to be the latest RC, and tells me that I'd better update to it. How come a daily build is behind snapshot releases like beta or RC?

I used the profile for my Firefox 4 on Windows, I had a few app tabs saved in the profile. What gives? How do I get the Firefox Menu Button to be orange or whatever color it's supposed to be?

Comment: where does it say that you should update?

Comment: Mozilla's start page.

Comment: Mozilla's start page doesn't recognise your version of firefox as it too new they only update the agent script for the site for the normal beta releases not the daily.

Comment: @Allan, but even the about page says 4.0b13pre.

Comment: Not sure about this but the last beta version was b12 the about page on normal beta shows "4.0 Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu Canonical - 1.0" presumably this is where they ppa's Fork presumably the rc branch will be bug fixing for release while the daily will be bringing in new features ready for 4.01 a1

Comment: The about page here says the same "4.0 Firefox for Ubuntu canonical - 1.0". I suspect it's nothing more than versioning for builds modified for Ubuntu. In any case, it'd only go for 4.01 after the actual 4.0 is released.

Comment: I fixed your wording.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to ask, but, the daily builds are newer than the rc, and you should ignore the mozilla start page as it almost never works with daily builds.

Comment: I'm running the stock version form mozilla.org -- it has in the past said 4.0b12 or 13 -- it now shows just 4.0.  Stopped using the ppa's for more control, and I've been very happy since.  Auto-update works, too.  If you're showing 4.0b13pre, that doesn't sound right to me either.

Comment: You should edit this question to ask a single question: "How come a daily build is behind snapshot releases like beta or RC?". In a forum you can unload a barrage of topical questions, but AskUbuntu only works with one question at a time.

Comment: FYi, you needn't ask a new question for getting a firefox shortcut on the dock. Follow these instructions till the unity bug is fixed: http://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity

Comment: @djeikyb, to avoid misunderstandings regarding Unity, I already added the 10.10. tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Simple Answer:

The Firefox Release Candidate (RC) is a refined build. The nightlies continue to be minefields. I would disable the nightly ppa. Then, download the RC to /opt and symlink `/opt/firefox/firefox` to `/usr/local/bin/firefox`. Once there is an official ppa for the RC releases maybe install that, but the RC from Mozilla should auto-update.

## RC vs Nightlies/Dailies:

I deduce, since [their launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ppa) has nothing to say for itself, that the Ubuntu Mozilla Daily team [pulls source](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Developer_Guide/Source_Code/Mercurial) from Firefox and builds it. That source code is the same foundation for Mozilla.org's [Nightly Builds](http://nightly.mozilla.org), which you can see is currently labeled by Mozilla.org: `firefox-4.0b13pre`. (Possibly I'm wrong, and the Ubuntu Daily Firefox team actually pulls source from mercurial that has passed basic tests. Regardless, it's in the same category as Mozilla.org's nightlies).

The Mozilla.org Firefox Release Candidate (RC) 1 is a nightly build tested, spit-polished, and renamed. It is not an official 4.0 release, which is why you don't see the nightly builds move from 4.0b13 to 4.01 or whathaveyou. The RC has its own source branch (which I'm sure you can get using [mercurial](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/)), but really won't be hacked on. You can also find the static source for RC1 at [the public ftp site](http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/4.0rc1/source/).

**The next RC** will not be built off of the RC1 code branch. It will be another nightly build tested, spit-polished, and renamed Mozilla Firefox RC2.

## More about nightly builds:

Mozilla.org has this to say about its nightly builds (thus also the launchpad-mozilla-daily's daily firefox builds):

> We make nightly builds for testing
>   only. We write code and post the
>   results right away so people like you
>   can join our testing process and
>   report bugs. You will find bugs, and
>   lots of them. Mozilla might crash on
>   startup. It might delete all your
>   files and cause your computer to burst
>   into flames. Don't bother downloading
>   nightly builds if you're unwilling to
>   put up with problems.

You'll note that Ubuntu-Mozilla-Daily's last attempt to [build Firefox failed](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ppa/+buildjob/2319981).

That said, the nightly builds should be fairly close to the release candidates, for reasons that should now be obvious.

Comment: But shouldn't the daily build say it's developing the next RC build like it said for the betas?

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but the nightlies are a different branch from the RCs now. The nightlies continue with normal changes, while the RC is relatively frozen excepting very minor tweaks here and there. In fact it's possible the RC may have tweaks in anticipation of public release that aren't in the nightlies.

Comment: If it's as you say, the version numbering should be more than 4.0 unlike what it says in the current about window.

Comment: It shouldn't change until 4 is a public release. There is no 4.0 release, therefore the official development branch should not be beyond 4.0. This is the behaviour I've seen in past Mozilla releases, and this one. **BTW, I'm assuming** that the daily-ppa is building off the nightlies.. http://nightly.mozilla.org/